# Drag and Drop work when debugging in visual studio but not on installed App

Tags: wpf

I have WPF app and i added some mouse events to a canvas in a window to enable drag and drop. it works fine when running the app from visual studio in debugging mode but it does not work when i run the app without debugging. can anyone help!

XAML

```
 <Canvas Name="canvas"
          Width="{Binding DialogWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Height="{Binding DialogHight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Transparent"
          PreviewMouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
          PreviewMouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
          PreviewMouseUp="Grid_MouseUp">
           <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                 <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt" />
           </Canvas.RenderTransform>
  </Canvas>
```

Code behind

```
        private Point _mStart;
        private Vector _mStartOffset;

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            var canvas = (Canvas) sender;
            var tt = canvas.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform ;
            _mStart = e.GetPosition(window);
            if (tt != null) _mStartOffset = new Vector(tt.X, tt.Y);
            canvas.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        { 
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
            var tt = canvas.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            if (tt == null) return;
            var window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            if (!canvas.IsMouseCaptured) return;
            var offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(window), _mStart);
           // if (-_mStartOffset.X + canvas.ActualWidth < window?.ActualWidth)
                 tt.X = _mStartOffset.X + offset.X * -1;
          //  if (-_mStartOffset.Y + canvas.ActualHeight < window?.ActualHeight)
                tt.Y = _mStartOffset.Y + offset.Y;
        }

        private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
            canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
```

Comment: You should show the code you are having problems with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Hey  Kevin Cook , thanx for responding i have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that Application.Current.MainWindow returns 0 for position (but Twist of fate it works in the debug mode as i mentioned before),
and when i used (UIElement)Application.Current.Resources["MainWindow"] it worked like a charm :)